# How do I yield from an ERB code block without rendering it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Consider the following:

**view.html.erb**:

```
<%= make_backwards do %>
  stressed
<% end %>
```

**helper.rb**:

```
def make_backwards
  yield.reverse
end
```

The view renders `stresseddesserts` instead of just `desserts`. How do I use the content in `yield` without rendering the code block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ERB has an internal buffer, which makes using blocks a bit more complicated, as you can see in your code example.

Rails provides a [capture](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-capture) method, which allows you to capture a string inside this buffer and return it from a block.

So your helper would become the following:

```
def make_backwards
  capture do
    yield.reverse
  end
end
```

Comment: Very useful Just for anyone else coming upon this, to embed the yielded block in another string: `"<div id=#{some_id}>\n#{capture {yield} }\n</div>"`

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing the ff:

Option 1:

```
<%= make_backwards { "stressed" } %>
```

Option 2:

```
<%= make_backwards do %>
  <% "stressed" %>
<% end %>
```

Let me know if it helps.